# Integration using Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Tags: calculus, integration

Given that \begin{align}
f(x) = \int_1^\sqrt x e^{-t^{2}}~dt
\end{align}
I was asked to find \begin{align} \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt x}~dx
\end{align}
I started by finding $f'(x)$, giving me $\frac{e^{-x}}{2\sqrt x}$, then attempting to link it to the 2nd equation with \begin{align} \frac12 \int_0^1 f'(x)~dx
\end{align}
Is my approach correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've calculated correctly,

$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{-x}}{2\sqrt{x}}$$

Using the above equation and applying integration by parts yields:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx$$

$$=|_{0}^{1} f(x) 2\sqrt{x} -\int_{0}^{1} 2\sqrt{x} \frac{e^{-x}}{2\sqrt{x}} dx$$

$$= 2f(1)-|_{0}^{1}(-e^{-x})$$

$$= 0+(e^{-1}-1)$$

$$=\frac{1}{e}-1$$

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a matter of integration by parts.

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}} dx$$

Let $u=f(x)$, so that $du = f'(x)dx$ (which you already found). Also, let $dv = \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $v=2 \sqrt{x} $. Integration by parts says:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}} = 2f(1) - 2\int_{0}^{1} \sqrt{x} f'(x)dx$$

clearly, $f(1) = 0$. So we're left with:

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}} = -\int_{0}^{1}{e^{-x}dx}$$